# Commenting c++ codes in Vim

Tags: c++, regex, vim, comments

I want to map \c to comment the current line in vim (add '// ' to before the first non-blank to the line) and \d to delete the '// ' at the beginning of line(uncomment).

I've added these two lines in my vimrc:

```
imap \c <Esc>:s/^/\/\/ <CR>j$a

imap \d <Esc>:s/^\/\/ /<CR>j$a
```

but when I call this in this line:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

then it is converted to:

```
//    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

but I want to convert it to:

```
    // for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

one of the reasons I want this is that when I want vim to indent this line, it will add an extra tab at the beginning of the line and convert it to:

```
    //    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

what should I do? I thought that ^ refers to first non-blank character of line but it wasn't true.

P.S: I've found these two commands, but I don't know what are they doing. could you please explain them to me (because I need to remember them and they're easier to remember when I know what are they). if any part of them is unnecessary please tell me:

```
imap \c <ESC>:s,^\(\s*\)[^/ \t]\@=,\1// ,e<CR>j$a

imap \d <ESC>:s,^\(\s*\)// \s\@!,\1,e<CR>j$a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About those commands you found:

> imap \c :s,^(\s*)[^# \t]\@=,\1// ,ej$a

Let's start with the pattern match, comparing it with your `:s/^/\/\/ <CR>j$a`.

- `:s,` is exactly equivalent to `:s/` - you can choose a nonstandard seperator where it makes the expression more readable, so here using `,` instead of `/` means less escaping, and no confusion between the comment `//` and the seperator
- `^(\s*)` matches the beginning of the line (same as yours) *and* any leading whitespace, capturing the whitespace so we can reuse it later
- `[^# \t]\@=` just requires some character other than space, tab or `#` before the line end, but doesn't capture it (ie, that character won't be replaced)
- `,\1// ,` replaces the matched string with the leading whitespace (`\1` is whatever was captured by the `(\s*)` group) followed by `//`

---

For example:

```
^    void foo();
```

should match like so: `^(\s*)[^# \t]\@=` -> `^(    )(v@=)void foo();`, ie, the first group matches the leading whitespace, and the next expression matches but doesn't consume the `v` from `void`.
Then, `\1//` expands to:

```
^    //
```

and the final substitution result is:

```
^    // void foo();`
```

(I've marked the start of line with `^` since the indentation is ambiguous otherwise)

Comment: what should I do if I want to add `//` to the `[^# \t]\@=` group?, and why \t and space is needed in this group (doesn't (\s*) capture them?)

Comment: I'll clarify the result of the substitution in the answer, but it currently puts '//' after the whitespace and before that first non-blank character ... if that isn't the behaviour you want, perhaps you could show the desired result?

Answer (score 3):

Even though the `^` normal mode command goes to the first non-blank, `^` in a pattern (so in the `:s`, `:g`, `:v`, `:sort` commands) means start of line. See `:help /^`

Use `I` to insert at first non-blank, and `A` to append after last character.

Use:

```
inoremap \c <c-o>I//<esc>jA
inoremap \d <esc>^2xjA
```

There are, however, good plugins that do the job. [commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) by Tim Pope, or the [NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218). See their documentation.

Comment: thanks, but the \d you've written, deletes the first two characters of line, even if the line is not commented.

Comment: Yes it will. If you don't want that: `inoremap \d <esc>:s@^\s*\zs//@@e<cr>jA` (using `@` as pattern delimiter makes it easier to include `/` in pattern).

Comment: @Farzam: did you try `inoremap \d <esc>:s@^\s*\zs//@@e<cr>jA` ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [Enhanced Commentify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23) plugin. You can then add this to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
let g:EnhCommentifyRespectIndent = 'yes'
```

and it will give you the behaviour you are after. In visual mode, select the area of code that you want to comment and then type `\c`. To uncomment use `\C`.

Comment: I prefer [Commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) or [tocmment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) as they both allow you to comment using motions. `\ ` is my comment prefix key so I can do `\aw` to comment a single word or `\aB` to comment out an entire block.

Comment: I prefer not to use plugins in this case because I want to use them in a contest that using plugins is not allowed.